# HTML Parsing and Auto Authentication in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, authentication, python-requests

I'm trying to write a Python script that will automatically authenticate a user so that the site can be parsed and (eventually) output relevant data. I can't seem solve the auto authentication problem, which is likely why the parsing will not take place. One issue is that the site we're trying to log on to does not change and is always the same IP. We're also not using a a "submit" on this webpage (line 18), so we're not sure how to go about modifying that so it fits out needs.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import sys

USER = ''
PASS = ''

URL = ''

def main():
# Start a session so we can have persistant cookies
session = requests.session(config={'verbose': sys.stderr})

# This is the form data that the page sends when logging in
login_data = {
    'InputPanel': USER,
    'InputPassword': PASS,
    'submit': 'login',
}

# Authenticate
r = session.post(URL, data=login_data)

# Try accessing a page that requires you to be logged in
r = session.get('')

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()

go('')

fv("1", "InputPanel", "")
fv("1", "InputPassword", "")

submit('0')

page = requests.get('')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

#Hours
hours = tree.xpath('//div[@class="staticObject"]/text()')
#Machine
projectors = tree.xpath('//div[@class1="corners dynamicObject"]/text()')

print 'Hours: ', hours
print 'Projectors: ', projectors
```

Searched for authentication in Python and found some results but not many seemed to apply to me. The code I have now is from an example I found, only as you'll see on line 25, there is no page we can't get to without being logged in, as the URL remains the same.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You should provide additional information. As I could find out is that go() and fv() is used by something called twill's Python API.

Comment: Sorry about that. I pasted an old form of the code. I added in the import twill.

Comment: That's not enough. This question is way too broad because you're talking about the entire concept of HTTP authentication in the whole wide field of Python. Also, you seem to be asking a question about a specific framework without tagging as such or really going into what you're trying to do with it. Try to narrow this down to what the issue actually is and fewer lines of (properly indented!) code. Too much text, not enough context.

Comment: @MikeEMKI the session variables/cookies etc will be on the `requests.session` so the `fv`/`go`/`submit` won't have that (it's like logging in with one browser, authenticating, then switching to another browser - not loggin in, and wondering why it doesn't work)... Can you drop twill and use `requests.post` to fill the form required instead - just post to  the form target and include values as you did with the authentication part.

Comment: I will go ahead and remove the twill sections and troubleshoot from there. Thank you.

Comment: I went ahead and edited my original post with better formatting and (hopefully) a better explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish. Hopefully you guys have a better understanding and can provide some help.

Comment: Better - but your indentation is a little off and `html` isn't the module you want to use - surprised you're not getting an `AttributeError` - I suspect instead you want an `import lxml.html` and `lxml.html.fromstring(page.text)`...

Comment: @MikeEMKI also you're not calling `session = requests.session` now... please can you ensure you do some more [edit]s addressing the comments - including any trackback you get (blank out anything you don't want made public that may appear in a stack trace)

Comment: @JonClements oh! I didn't realize past edits could be seen. I can't figure out how to delete them though. Can you clarify what you mean by blanking them out?

Comment: @MikeEMKI if any passwords or your IP address appear in them for example....

Answer (score 0):

Without more information this is hard to answer. You could just go ahead and do the post request using

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

(https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) for the login and catch the session that it outputs, if it's a header/cookie you can catch them and use them for the rest of the session but you'll likely have to pass them for each page request. There isn't really enough information in your question to give you a full in depth answer here.

If you're parsing html you may want to look at http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: I looked into bs4, but it doesn't hurt to take another look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try mechanize module in python?

It is pretty handy when tweaking especially with submission button and forms.

Comment: Twill is a wrapper around the `mechanize` module :)

Comment: Oh.. I see. I didn't try it yet. But I guess, we have more control on webpages with mechanize than Twill. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Right now I am working with authentication as well. I simplified the part for you. It was actually a part of a class.

```
def func1(self):
    """
    Authentication
    Parameters: none
    """
    USER = 'username'
    PASS = 'password'
    URL = 'http://[ip]'
    payload = {"InputPanel": USER,
               "InputPassword": PASS,
               "submit": "login"}

    response = requests.post(self.URL, data=payload, verify=True)
    if response.status_code is not 200:
        raise AuthError(response.reason)
    auth_info = response.json()
    return auth_info
```

I do not know if this will work as it is because I recode and removed a lot of code. You will probably need some imports (requests,json). Also AuthError will give you an error since you do not have this class - you can comment the lines ..if and ..auth_info with # so it will not be executed.